# How to structure data model for an advertising tool in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture, mongodb, ads

I am building an ad analytics tool which assumes a data structure like this:

- Account
- Campaign
- Keyword
- Conversion

I have a lot of information about individual conversion events, which can be tied back to the cost data of each campaign, keyword, ad group, etc. In SQL, you could consider each property a sort of foreign key (text-based) to the campaign, keyword or ad in a particular account, but that's inefficient and slow. It doesn't sound like a great idea to make campaign_id, keyword_id, etc. fields and populate them either, because I want the analytics to be available in near-real time.

What would be a good way to model this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that MongoDB is really the right choice for something like this, since MongoDB is really more about storing less well (or more complex) documents rather than hierarchical records like this one.  However, if you are going the MongoDB route, then you can just use the account, campaign and keyword tags directly.  There is no substantive benefit to abstracting these into meaningless keys in MongoDB.  You can index these fields directly in MongoDB.

I don't know what your volumes are going to be and what other factors are affecting your technology choices.  However, assuming that your accounts, campaigns and keywords don't change *that* frequently, you could do this with plain old RDBMS (SQL or Oracle etc.) using lookup tables for these determinants where the foreign keys are meaningless integers.  If you're doing live analytics you could adopt a star schema and keep all of the numeric FKs on the base fact table (Conversion) so that you aren't joining a chain of four tables to get the whole picture, instead you'd be doing three one-hop joins.  This would allow you to summarize at any level with only a single join.

Comment: Actually using Conversion as the central point and joining from there might be a good solution... I will give that a try. What if I made the foreign keys strings instead of integers. Would that kill performance?

Comment: Your foreign keys will be stored in indexes so if your strings are big then the indexes will be big and it will take longer to traverse them due to the IO involved.  On the other hand, if your strings aren't too big, it might be better to use the strings instead of integers since queries may be able to use the index value directly without an additional lookup.  There's no way to tell without trying it both ways and doing some profiling.  I lean towards integer psuedo keys in general and move to strings if necessary.  This is especially true if your string values might _ever_ change.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a very high volume of conversion events (millions per day or more), a storage engine alone (MongoDB or anything else) won't help you. What you need is the ability to run map-reduce jobs on the data in order to calculate the analytics. You can scale-out your cluster as necessary to achieve near-real time performance.

The free/open-source options that I can suggest are Hadoop (and probably HBase and Hive) or Riak. 
There are other options - I'm only suggesting these two because I've personal experience with them in a high scale production environment. We're currently using Hadoop to power an analytics system processing billions of events per day.

If you're not into rolling your own and are able and willing to pay (a lot!) then look at GreenPlum and Vertica.

I'll be happy to share more information on potential solution designs - but I'll need more data on what you're trying to achieve - scale, use cases etc.